Getting vertex failed exception when execute Hive query +jdbc
getting below error upon running query
java.sql.SQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 10, vertexId=vertex_1712558850503_8609_2_01, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1712558850503_8609_2_01_000006, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1712558850503_8609_2_01_000006_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:298)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:252)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:75)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:62)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1898)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:62)
at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:38)
at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:437)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:269)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorMapOperator.process(VectorMapOperator.java:970)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.processRow(MapRecordSource.java:92)
... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found any.data.NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record, expecting any.data.NiFi_ExecuteSQL_Record, missing required field block_trade
I am trying to fetch data from hive with query

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
